# Example for SimplexSolver in Apache Commons Maths 3.6.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-commons, simplex-algorithm, linear-optimization

I am new to linear optimization and currently trying to use the `SimplexSolver.class` from `org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear`.

So I looked up some examples on how to use it, to understand it and also to recall what the  Simplex Algorithm exactly processes and how it works.

But unfortunately, I encountered some problems. For all the examples I was able to find, the class is used in that way:

```
PointValuePair s = new SimplexSolver().optimize(function, constraints, GoalType.MINIMIZE, false);
```

But the parameters in the example don't fit with the current expectation of the function `optimize`. Checking out the documentation was not very helpful for me, because it just says that I need one parameter of type `OptimizationData`. Because `OptimizationData` is just an interface, I don't really know which type to use.

Does anyone have an example of how to use the `optimize` function properly?

Comment: You can use any class that implements the interface. See [What is an Interfece?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). As for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954235/hello-world-example-for-simplexsolver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hello World example for SimplexSolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954235/hello-world-example-for-simplexsolver)

Comment: Unfortunately, I already saw this one and it does not help. In the provided example the only answer again contains only `solver.optimize(new MaxIter(100), f, ... , ...., ... );`. And as I have stated in my question, calling the method with multiple parameters is no longer possible. So the provided answer to the linked post does not even satisfy the original question of the post.